# How to read the header values of c:import url in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

Is it possible to read header values of c:import url in jsp.

```
<c:import url="http://test.com/test.jsp/" />
```

Here "http://test.com/test.jsp/" is external url . I would like to read the header values of that external.

```
Note: The external url have iframe and cross origin policy.
```

Give me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I think.. either you need to prefetch those values. And later you can include it/ display it/ use it wherever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. If you really need to include some external content (+ reading its headers), you will have to fetch that content in a server-side controller/action (there you will have access to the headers).

Answer (score 0):

Using c:import cant able to get the header values and its only used for print the url source code. 
NOTE: It is a machine to machine call.